# Woocommerce search page product image is missing. How to solve?

Tags: image, search, woocommerce

after last woocommerce update i can't see product image on search page? Anyone can solve my problem? I have some problem on desktop and mobile!

Take a look here: https://bresciapc.com/?s=iphone

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Something is wrong with your jQuery: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).click is not a function` Try disabling all 3rd party plugins of WooCommerce - maybe one of them makes probems.

Comment: I have only 4 plugins in total, i disabled 2 but same problem

Comment: Try to save your permalink structure again!